# Долгая работа Zabbix скриптов

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, zabbix

После очередного апдейта софта стали долго отрабатываться скрипты для заббикса. Причем только на одном сервере на других тоже апдейтнулся и там все норм. В вэб морде начались алерты

```
Php-fpm is down
```

и

```
Nginx responce is invalid
```

Вручную запускал скрипты отрабатываются очень долго, подскажите куда хотябы копать.

Если просто запросить статус у сервисов то они отвечают быстро, так что подозрение на комманды в скрипте

Скрипты для заббикса

Конфиг для nginx

```
#!/bin/bash

PREFIX='nginx'
URL='http://127.0.0.1/server-status'

CURL='/usr/bin/curl'
TMP='/tmp/nginx-ping.tmp'
SENDER='/usr/bin/zabbix_sender'
CONFIG='/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf'

if [ ! -x ${CURL} ]
then echo Seems, path to curl is incorrect or not installed. && exit 0
else if [ ! -x ${SENDER} ]
then echo Seems, path to zabbix_sender is incorrect or not installed. && exit 0
else if [ ! -f ${CONFIG} ]
then echo Seems, path to zabbix_agentd.conf is incorrect && exit 0
fi fi fi

read -a s <<< `(time ${CURL} --no-keepalive -s -m 9 ${URL}) 2>$TMP`

if [[ "${s[7]}" =~ ([0-9]+) ]]
then
echo "\
- ${PREFIX}.accepts ${s[7]}
- ${PREFIX}.connections.active ${s[2]}
- ${PREFIX}.connections.reading ${s[11]}
- ${PREFIX}.connections.waiting ${s[15]}
- ${PREFIX}.connections.writing ${s[13]}
- ${PREFIX}.handled ${s[8]}
- ${PREFIX}.requests ${s[9]}" | ${SENDER} -c ${CONFIG} -i - >/dev/null 2>&1
awk '/real/{split($2,a,"[ms]");print a[1]*60+a[2];}' $TMP
else
echo '-0.001'
fi
rm $TMP
exit 1
```

Пример конфика для php-fpm

```
#!/bin/bash

PREFIX='php.fpm'
URL='http://127.0.0.1/status'

CURL='/usr/bin/curl'
TMP='/tmp/php-fpm-ping.tmp'
SENDER='/usr/bin/zabbix_sender'
CONFIG='/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf'

if [ ! -x ${CURL} ]
then echo Seems, path to curl is incorrect or not installed. && exit 0
else if [ ! -x ${SENDER} ]
then echo Seems, path to zabbix_sender is incorrect or not installed. && exit 0
else if [ ! -f ${CONFIG} ]
then echo Seems, path to zabbix_agentd.conf is incorrect && exit 0
fi fi fi

(time ${CURL} --no-keepalive -sm3 ${URL}) 2>$TMP | awk --assign pr="- ${PREFIX}." '
/^accepted c/ {print pr"accepted_conn "$3}
/^active proc/ {print pr"active_processes "$3}
/^idle proc/ {print pr"idle_processes "$3}
/^listen queue:/ {print pr"listen_queue_len "$3}
/^max children reach/ {print pr"max_children_reached "$4}
/^max listen queue:/ {print pr"max_listen_queue_len "$4}' | ${SENDER} -c ${CONFIG} -i - 2>/dev/null | awk --assign t="${TMP}" '/^sent/{if($6==0){print"-0.001";print>t}}'
awk '/real/{split($2,a,"[ms]");print a[1]*60+a[2];}' $TMP
rm $TMP
exit 1
```

Comment: запустите с `bash -x` ставлю на проблему с dns на клиенте

Comment: @zb' зависает на этом моменте /usr/bin/zabbix_sender -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf -i -

Answer (score 0):

В bash 4.4 пофиксили какую-то старую багу и скрипт перестал работать. Мне помогло вот это:

```
diff --git a/nginx-status.sh b/nginx-status.sh
index 8e671e0..0adf509 100644
--- a/nginx-status.sh
+++ b/nginx-status.sh
@@ -17,7 +17,8 @@ else if [ ! -f ${CONFIG} ]
 then echo Seems, path to zabbix_agentd.conf is incorrect && exit 0
 fi fi fi

-read -a s <<< `(time ${CURL} --no-keepalive -s -m 9 ${URL}) 2>$TMP`
+k=`(time ${CURL} --no-keepalive -s -m 9 ${URL}) 2>$TMP`
+read -a s <<< `echo ${k}`

 if [[ "${s[7]}" =~ ([0-9]+) ]]
 then
```